# How to hide button without affecting its functionality

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

From above picture the `Login` button has functionality to allow subscribed users  . I have a scenario to hide login button as well as to allow subscribed users.

For hiding I have written like this:

```
GameObject.FindWithTag("Login_btn").active = false;
```

When I write this code, it hides the login button as expected but it also disables subscribed users functionality   and throws an exception

> Coroutine couldn't be started because the the game object 'Login_btn' is inactive

Could you help me with this?

Comment: Is this script attached to the button? In that case, you could try to attach it to another GameObject that won't be deactivated.

Answer (score 2):

Make its texture a PNG with an alpha of 1. Therefore nobody will see it, but it'll be there to the game engine.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way of doing this where you don't need to have another PNG is to just use

```
MyButton.GetComponent<Image>().sprite.color = Color.clear;
```

If your button is a sprite and not UI image that you have set the colour manually on, you can just use Color.white to revert it back otherwise just grab a reference to it before you call that first line and reference it when you want to show it again like this:

```
Color col = new color();
void SwitchColour(bool b){
   Image myImage = Button.GetComponent<Image>();
   if(!b){
      col = myImage.color;
      myImage.color = Color.clear;
   }else myImage.color = col;
}
```

Comment: Up-voted simply because I won't be needing `new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)` anymore :)

Comment: Gotta love those shortcuts!